# Can a database name start with a number?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm wondering if a database name can start with a number e.g 143doors.

I found some answer here http://markmail.org/message/yw57rt3tweldtxet but I'm not quite sure since it's 1999.

Will there be disadvantages if I start with a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick test says, yes you can.  Using spaces in database names will lead to trouble, though. You'll have to use `143 doors` (with the backtick) if you really want to do this.

Comment: Hmmm someone edited my question, it should have no spaces... just 143doors. Thanks... I already did... I'm just wondering if there would be any issues if I did this.

Comment: StackOverflow ate my `` syntax, sorry.  Yes, the space works, but I really don't recommend it.

Answer (score 2):

Within MySQL Workbench, you are going to have trouble querying if you do something like {db_name}.{table} and your db_name starts with a number.

The solution to this is the backtick mentioned in the accepted answer.  An example is like:

```
select * from `2013e93`.blurb
```

where the db_name is 2013e93 and the table is blurb.